# Why doesn't custom search enable "Actions" items for selected records after upgrade to 4.6.3?

Tags: custom-search

I have a custom search extension and it was working fine in 4.4.14.
Since I have upgraded to 4.6.3, "Actions" items only enabled for All records. But if I select certain records from result it does not enable "Actions" items. My custom PHP & a screenshot is shown below.

```
    <?php

/**
 * A custom contact search
 */
class CRM_Guestsearch_Form_Search_Guestsearch extends CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_Base implements CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Interface {

  function __construct(&$formValues) {
    parent::__construct($formValues);
  }

  /**
   * Prepare a set of search fields
   *
   * @param CRM_Core_Form $form modifiable
   * @return void
   */
  function buildForm(&$form) {
    CRM_Utils_System::setTitle(ts('Registered Guest (Unassigned)'));

  /**
    $form->add('text', 'name', ts('Name'), TRUE
    );

    $form->setDefaults(array(
      'name' => '',
    ));
     */
    /**
     * if you are using the standard template, this array tells the template what elements
     * are part of the search criteria
     */
    $form->assign('elements', array('name'));
  }

  /**
   * Get a list of summary data points
   *
   * @return mixed; NULL or array with keys:
   *  - summary: string
   *  - total: numeric
   */
  function summary() {
    return NULL;
    // return array(
    //   'summary' => 'This is a summary',
    //   'total' => 50.0,
    // );
  }

  /**
   * Get a list of displayable columns
   *
   * @return array, keys are printable column headers and values are SQL column names
   */
  function &columns() {
    // return by reference
    $columns = array(
      ts('Contact Source') => 'source',
      ts('Name') => 'sort_name',
      ts('Phone') => 'phone',
      ts('Email') => 'email',
      ts('Date of visit') => CIVICRM_GUESTSEARCH_CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME,
    );
    return $columns;
  }

  /**
   * Construct a full SQL query which returns one page worth of results
   *
   * @param int $offset
   * @param int $rowcount
   * @param null $sort
   * @param bool $includeContactIDs
   * @param bool $justIDs
   * @return string, sql
   */
  function all($offset = 0, $rowcount = 0, $sort = NULL, $includeContactIDs = FALSE, $justIDs = FALSE) {

    return $this->sql($this->select(), $offset, $rowcount, null, $includeContactIDs, NULL);
  }

  /**
   * Construct a SQL SELECT clause
   *
   * @return string, sql fragment with SELECT arguments
   */
  function select() {
    return "
      contact_a.id                  as contact_id,
      contact_a.source              as source,
      contact_a.contact_sub_type    as contact_sub_type,
      contact_a.sort_name           as sort_name,
      phone.phone ,
      email.email  ,
      date.
    " . CIVICRM_GUESTSEARCH_CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME;
  }

  /**
   * Construct a SQL FROM clause
   *
   * @return string, sql fragment with FROM and JOIN clauses
   */
  function from() {
    return "
      FROM      civicrm_contact contact_a
      LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity_contact a ON (a.contact_id = contact_a.id)
      LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone phone ON (phone.contact_id = contact_a.id)
      LEFT JOIN civicrm_email email ON (email.contact_id = contact_a.id)
      LEFT JOIN " . CIVICRM_GUESTSEARCH_CUSTOM_TABLE_NAME . " date ON (date.entity_id = contact_a.id)
    ";
  }

  /**
   * Construct a SQL WHERE clause
   *
   * @param bool $includeContactIDs
   * @return string, sql fragment with conditional expressions
   */
  function where($includeContactIDs = false) {
    $params = array();

    $where = "contact_a.contact_sub_type = 'Guest' AND contact_a.source = 'Guest Greeter Signup' AND activity_id IS NULL ORDER BY date." . CIVICRM_GUESTSEARCH_CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME . " ASC ";

    return $where;

  }

  /**
   * Determine the Smarty template for the search screen
   *
   * @return string, template path (findable through Smarty template path)
   */
  function templateFile() {
    return 'CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom.tpl';
  }

  /**
   * Modify the content of each row
   *
   * @param array $row modifiable SQL result row
   * @return void
   */

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you reviewed the wiki to see if there is any documentation on changes for searches from 4.4 to 4.6?

Comment: I did, but cant seems to find any significant difference..!!!

Answer (score 3):

Since the number of selected records hasn't updated when you check the box, that suggests it's possibly a Javascript error.  Try the steps in [Troubleshooting JavaScript in CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) and post back any new diagnostic info you find.

Comment: I have ran diagnostics and reported in this thread. Because this was happening all search function not only in custom search. http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/javascript-prevents-search-function-selecting-result-not-enabling-action-men

Answer (score 2):

In 2021 is the same problem. In custom search you can't enable actions. But I find solution. I looked to the js file which count checkboxes and I found out that you just need remove "crm-ajax-selection-form" class from your search form. You can add to your tpl file somethink like this:
`<script> {literal} CRM.$(".crm-ajax-selection-form").removeClass("crm-ajax-selection-form"); {/literal} </script>`
2 hours reverse engineering was worth it. :D

Answer (score 0):

I am running into exactly the same problem (ie selecting some records does not activate the "Actions" button.  It is happening with a custom search that was generated by "civix". (I only changed the title)

Did anyone find a solution?

Source code is: `

> /**  * A custom contact search  */ class
>   CRM_Financialsummaries_Form_Search_preparestatements extends
>   CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_Base implements
>   CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Interface {   function
>   __construct(&$formValues) {
>       parent::__construct($formValues);   }
>
> /**    * Prepare a set of search fields    *    * @param
>   CRM_Core_Form $form modifiable    * @return void    */   function
>   buildForm(&$form) {
>       CRM_Utils_System::setTitle(ts('Prepare Statements'));
>
> ```
> $form->add('text',
>   'household_name',
>   ts('Household Name'),
>   TRUE
> );
>
> $stateProvince = array('' => ts('- any state/province -')) + CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::stateProvince();
> $form->addElement('select', 'state_province_id', ts('State/Province'), $stateProvince);
>
> // Optionally define default search values
> $form->setDefaults(array(
>   'household_name' => '',
>   'state_province_id' => NULL,
> ));
>
> /**
>  * if you are using the standard template, this array tells the template what elements
>  * are part of the search criteria
>  */
> $form->assign('elements', array('household_name', 'state_province_id'));   }
> ```
>
> /**    * Get a list of summary data points    *    * @return mixed;
>   NULL or array with keys:    *  - summary: string    *  - total:
>   numeric    */   function summary() {
>       return NULL;
>       // return array(
>       //   'summary' => 'This is a summary',
>       //   'total' => 50.0,
>       // );   }
>
> /**    * Get a list of displayable columns    *    * @return array,
>   keys are printable column headers and values are SQL column names
>   */   function &columns() {
>       // return by reference
>       $columns = array(
>         ts('Contact Id') => 'contact_id',
>         ts('Contact Type') => 'contact_type',
>         ts('Name') => 'sort_name',
>         ts('State') => 'state_province',
>       );
>       return $columns;   }
>
> /**    * Construct a full SQL query which returns one page worth of
>   results    *    * @param int $offset    * @param int $rowcount    *
>   @param null $sort    * @param bool $includeContactIDs    * @param bool
>   $justIDs    * @return string, sql    */   function all($offset = 0,
>   $rowcount = 0, $sort = NULL, $includeContactIDs = FALSE, $justIDs =
>   FALSE) {
>       // delegate to $this->sql(), $this->select(), $this->from(), $this->where(), etc.
>       return $this->sql($this->select(), $offset, $rowcount, $sort, $includeContactIDs, NULL);   }
>
> /**    * Construct a SQL SELECT clause    *    * @return string, sql
>   fragment with SELECT arguments    */   function select() {
>       return "
>         contact_a.id           as contact_id  ,
>         contact_a.contact_type as contact_type,
>         contact_a.sort_name    as sort_name,
>         state_province.name    as state_province
>       ";   }
>
> /**    * Construct a SQL FROM clause    *    * @return string, sql
>   fragment with FROM and JOIN clauses    */   function from() {
>       return "
>         FROM      civicrm_contact contact_a
>         LEFT JOIN civicrm_address address ON ( address.contact_id       = contact_a.id AND
>                                                address.is_primary       = 1 )
>         LEFT JOIN civicrm_email           ON ( civicrm_email.contact_id = contact_a.id AND
>                                                civicrm_email.is_primary = 1 )
>         LEFT JOIN civicrm_state_province state_province ON state_province.id = address.state_province_id
>       ";   }
>
> /**    * Construct a SQL WHERE clause    *    * @param bool
>   $includeContactIDs    * @return string, sql fragment with conditional
>   expressions    */   function where($includeContactIDs = FALSE) {
>       $params = array();
>       $where = "contact_a.contact_type   = 'Household'";
>
> ```
> $count  = 1;
> $clause = array();
> $name   = CRM_Utils_Array::value('household_name',
>   $this->_formValues
> );
> if ($name != NULL) {
>   if (strpos($name, '%') === FALSE) {
>     $name = "%{$name}%";
>   }
>   $params[$count] = array($name, 'String');
>   $clause[] = "contact_a.household_name LIKE %{$count}";
>   $count++;
> }
>
> $state = CRM_Utils_Array::value('state_province_id',
>   $this->_formValues
> );
> if (!$state &&
>   $this->_stateID
> ) {
>   $state = $this->_stateID;
> }
>
> if ($state) {
>   $params[$count] = array($state, 'Integer');
>   $clause[] = "state_province.id = %{$count}";
> }
>
> if (!empty($clause)) {
>   $where .= ' AND ' . implode(' AND ', $clause);
> }
>
> return $this->whereClause($where, $params);   }
> ```
>
> /**    * Determine the Smarty template for the search screen    *
>   * @return string, template path (findable through Smarty template path)    */   function templateFile() {
>       return 'CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom.tpl';   }
>
> /**    * Modify the content of each row    *    * @param array $row
>   modifiable SQL result row    * @return void    */   function
>   alterRow(&$row) {
>       $row['sort_name'] .= ' ( altered )';   } }`