# Javascript prevents search function!! Selecting result not enabling "Action" menu after upgrading to 4.6.4?

Tags: search-results, custom-search

On 4.4 install it was working perfectly. Since I have upgraded to 4.6.4 from 4.4.16 When I do a search (Search ...Custom Searches ... Basic Search) and I get a list of contacts that is more than 1 page, trying to use the "select all rows" check box prevents use of any search actions. ( the search box is frozen, and the count of selected records remains at 0).

[image]

But if I select certain records then I am able to get the action menu...

[image]

I have tried to produce it to civicrm demo site but it seemed ok in there. During upgrade everything was fine and did not get any error message. I just cant figure out how to sort this problem. If anyone can help that would greatly appreciated. I have cleared cache but no luck.

This is the log from civicrm

```
Jun 26 21:57:10  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] =>  [nativecode=1065 ** Query was empty]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] =>  [nativecode=1065 ** Query was empty]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info=" [nativecode=1065 ** Query was empty]"]
)

Jun 26 21:57:10  [info] $backTrace = #0 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(235): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), " [nativecode=1065 ** Query was empty]")
#4 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, (Array:2), " [nativecode=1065 ** Query was empty]")
#5 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, " [nativecode=1065 ** Query was empty]", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(899): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1065 ** Query was empty")
#7 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("")
#9 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("")
#10 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("")
#11 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("")
#12 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1179): CRM_Core_DAO->query("", TRUE)
#13 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/PrevNextCache.php(394): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery(NULL, (Array:0))
#14 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/AJAX.php(766): CRM_Core_BAO_PrevNextCache::markSelection("civicrm search c3e2c2fdbc11492ac2deb78c68dd3f3b_6386", "select")
#15 [internal function](): CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX::selectUnselectContacts()
#16 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func((Array:2))
#17 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#18 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#19 /srv/www/rldb/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#20 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "markSelection")
#21 /srv/www/rldb/includes/menu.inc(519): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#22 /srv/www/rldb/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#23 {main}
```

Results from firebug

```
GET https://abcd.info/civicrm/ajax/markSelection?qfKe..._622-mark_x_297-mark_x_88-mark_x_153-mark_x_1314

200 OK
        357ms   
js_2qPg...vKsA.js (line 946)
ParamsHeadersResponseJSONCookies

{"getCount":0}

GET https://abcd.info/civicrm/ajax/markSelection?qfKe..._622-mark_x_297-mark_x_88-mark_x_153-mark_x_1314

    200 OK
            336ms   
    js_2qPg...vKsA.js (line 946)
    ParamsHeadersResponseHTMLCookies

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict
    .dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

    <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <base href="/sites/all/modules/civicrm/"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/civicrm.css" type="text/css" media="screen"
    ><link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness
    /jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <div class="messages status no-popup">  <div class="icon red-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
     <span class="status-fatal">Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.</span>
        <div class="crm-section crm-error-message"></div>
                <hr style="solid 1px"/>
            <div class="crm-section crm-error-message">DB Error: unknown error</div>
                <p><a href="https://abcd.info/" title="Main Menu">Return to home page.</a></p>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <script language="JavaScript">function toggle(element){var className=element.className;if(className=
    ='crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'){element.className='crm-accordion-wrapper
      crm-fatal-error-details-block';}else{element.className='crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'
    ;}}</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please edit your original question with additional info instead of creating a duplicate question.

Comment: This question is more complete than the previous one. Therefore this can be kept and the other can be deleted.